# What is "extension aggregate" and why do I need it?

Tags: sqlite, ada

I'm trying to use GNAT's SQLite bindings. And I want some way to get errors from these bindings.  Trying to read through the code, I found that I can set up the connection by providing a mystery object that is supposed to handle errors...

No matter how I try to shape and provide this object, the library either won't accept it, or I get runtime access check errors (another bizarre aspect of this program as the pointer should be always alive since it's never leaving the scope of the procedure that declared it... but maybe it works differently in Ada).

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
type of aggregate has private ancestor "Error_Reporter"
must use extension aggregate
```

The original `Error_Reporter` is defined as follows:

```
type Error_Reporter is abstract tagged private;
...
private

   type Error_Reporter is abstract tagged null record;
```

Anyways, below is the outline of the problematic code:

The header file:

```
   -- type Error_Handler is new Gse.Error_Reporter with private;
   type Error_Handler is new Gse.Error_Reporter with record
      Message : Asu.Unbounded_String;
   end record;
   
   type Error_Handler_Access is access Error_Handler;

   procedure On_Error
     (Self       : in out Error_Handler;
      Connection : access Gse.Database_Connection_Record'Class;
      Message    : String);

-- more stuff ...
   
-- private
--    type Error_Handler is new Gse.Error_Reporter with record
--       Message : Asu.Unbounded_String;
--    end record;
```

the implementation:

```
...
      declare
         pragma Suppress (Accessibility_Check);
         -- Handler : constant Error_Handler_Access :=
         --   new Error_Handler'(Message => Asu.Null_Unbounded_String);
         Handler : constant access Error_Handler :=
           new Error_Handler'(Message => Asu.Null_Unbounded_String);
         -- Handler : aliased Error_Handler;
         Descr         : Gse.Database_Description    :=
           Gss.Setup (Db_File, Errors => Handler);
--         Gss.Setup (Db_File, Errors => Handler'Access);
...
```

Commented code shows various things I tried.  (Also, `pragma` has no effect).

Ideally, I don't want to `new` anything, unless this is the requirement from GNAT's interface.

Even better: if I could entirely avoid using this object (it should be possible to salvage the actual Sqlite connection from this wrapper and get access to return code and the error message), but the code is not very easy to read and is trying to make the user do things that I don't want (ORM, multiple layers of bindings that only complicate things) all while hiding the essential useful functionality.  I'd appreciate any guidance in this direction.

---

UPDATE: In the end, my problem was I couldn't figure out how to use `Bind_XXX` group of procedures from `Gnade` package.  And this is what prompted me to use the `Execute` package, which ultimately led to the problem with error reporting.  To solve this, I finally figured out how to use `Bind_XXX` (the one giving me the most problems was `Bind_Text` due to pointer translation between Ada and C).  Once that worked, I rewrote the code to use just `Gnade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Error_Handler extends Gse.Error_Handler, your instantiations need to specify the base class.  Try:

```ada
Handler : constant access Error_Handler :=
           new Error_Handler'(Gse.Error_Handler with Message => Asu.Null_Unbounded_String);
```

That provides the base class along with your child class members

Comment: Thank you. This allows it to compile, but I'm back to "accessibility check failed". I don't know if these two errors are related (i.e. I'm supposed to create this object differently), or is it something else related to some other aspect of my code. Would you happen to have any insight into this?

Comment: @wvxvw They aren't strictly related.  I would recommend marking this solved and posting another question about the accessibility check issue, with maybe a bit more code (a small compilable example with the error). Note that you are using the "new" operator to allocate a variable and saving it to an anonymous access variable.  That is generally frowned apon.  You should be using named access types with "new".  Something like:  type Handler_Access is access Error_Handler; Handler : constant Handler_Access :=  new Error_Handler'(<stuff>);  Note that that type definition should be library level.

Comment: @Jere, like the type `Error_Handler_Access` already declared in the line after `Error_Handler`? /s

Comment: @SimonWright Sorry about that.  I have vision problems that come and go.  I just missed it was all.  Yes @wvxvw should use his already defined access type ```Error_Handler_Access``` instead of the anonymous access variable.